# Не удается импортировать NotificationBuilder из plyer

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

У меня по факту код состоит из 1 строчки:

```
from plyer.platforms.android.notification import NotificationBuilder
```

Именно данный импорт создает мне проблему, то есть, ошибку:

```
jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: android/os/Build$VERSION java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Java у меня установлена, как и JDK, переменная среда JAVA_HOME.

Comment: https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/plyer/platforms/android/notification.py  смотрим первоисточник. NotificationBuilder это функция autoclass() .смотрим выше from jnius import autoclass. вам не джаву нужно ставить а модуль jnius.

Comment: добавлю что на главной странице How? 
Plyer tries not to reinvent the wheel, and will call for external libraries to implement the api in the easiest way, depending on the current platform.

on python-for-android, __pyjnius__ is used